# How to delete and re insert in update a relation Kotlin + Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I have a relation with two entities, Coverage and Points. Wen i send data to create at Coverage endpoint, i send somethig similiar to:

```
points: [
   { lat: 10, lon: 20}, {lat:20, lon:15}
]
```

this created a coverage data and points with the correct relation to the coverage. Now, i wanna in the updated method send same request with different data and, in background, delete all points related to the coverage and re-insert this news.

How i can do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your coverage object can have a method that change the value of the field in the coverage object. When new data is assigned with the method shown below, the old data will be destroyed by the garbage collector if their is no other references to it.

```
class Coverage {
    fun setPoints(points : Array<Point>){
        // Use the points to modify the data of the class appropriately.
    }
}
```